# Laravel Sentry: Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidOptionsException when configuring Sentry in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, monitoring, sentry, laravel-10

I'm new to the Sentry package in Laravel but just opened an account and made a project in its website.

Then after installing the package on my project, I tried running `pecl install excimer` and then added this to `App/Exceptions/Handler.php:` :

```
public function register() {
  $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
    if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
      app('sentry')->captureException($e);
    }
  });
}
```

And also made a new file called `sentry.php` in the config directory which goes like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'dsn' => env('SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN')
];
```

Then I copied and pasted the value of DSN in the **Client Keys** of my sentry.io project settings page.

But when I run `php artisan sentry:publish` I get this message:

```
 Enable Performance Monitoring? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 Do you want to send a test event & transaction to Sentry? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

DSN discovered from Laravel config or `.env` file!
Sending test event...
There was an error sending the event.
Please check if your DSN is set properly in your `.env` as `SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN` or in your config file `config/sentry.php`.
```

And in the .env file, I have called the given DSN:

SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN=COPIED_AND_PASTED_DSN

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue and use the Sentry package properly?